# Расширение Диска 0 за счет Диска 1

Tags: windows, память, диск

Дела обстоят так: в `Диске 0` - есть `Диск С` и у него память 111гб, в то время как в `Диске 1` находит `Диск N`, и был `диск D`, но его очистил и хотел расширить за счет него `диск С`, в разных туториалах говорится как это делать пример здесь `https://remontka.pro/merge-disk-partitions-windows/` но мне это не подходит, так в этих видео показано что `Диск С` и `Диск D` расположены в одном пространстве(если правильно так выражаться) у меня на разных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть я могу расширить `Диск N`, но не могу расширить `Диск С`, если варианты как сделать это без переустановки, опция `расширить Том` мне не доступна так как для `Диска 0` доступна только 111гб.

Comment: По вашей ссылке речь о разделах на одном диске, а не о разных дисках. Посмотрите тут https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-one-large-volume-using-multiple-hard-drives-windows-10

Comment: Можно использовать https://www.partitionwizard.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для размазыванися одного раздела по двум физическим дискам используется технология програмного raid, которая называется "динамические диски". Вроде в этой статье описанно https://remontcompa.ru/windows/funkcional-windows/1700-chto-takoe-dinamicheskie-diski.html

Нужно преобразовать диски к динамическим и тогда получится расширить раздел на другой физический.

Но возможно не получится сделать из системного диска С: составной том

Comment: статья полезная, как раз то что искал, но мне не помогло, т.к. мне комп не позволил создать составной том.

Comment: С диском С всегда проблемы